# julia how to use Plots

Tags: julia, plots.jl

When I try and use Plots, It errors. Please help me, how can I deal with it? I am using Julia v1.3.0 and did `Pgk.add("Plots")` to  downloads  so I don't know why I have this problem...  Is the version of Julia or the Plots package wrong? (I am on macOS, is that the issue?)

```
using Plots
```

```
[ Info: Precompiling Plots [91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80]
ERROR: LoadError: EOFError: read end of file
Stacktrace:
 [1] read(::IOStream, ::Type{Int64}) at ./iostream.jl:361
 [2] parse_cache_header(::IOStream) at ./loading.jl:1334
 [3] stale_cachefile(::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1413
 [4] _require_search_from_serialized(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:752
 [5] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:1001
 [6] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:922
 [7] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:917
 [8] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [9] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1105
 [10] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:31
 [11] top-level scope at none:2
 [12] eval at ./boot.jl:330 [inlined]
 [13] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:425
 [14] top-level scope at ./none:3
in expression starting at /Users/owls/.julia/packages/Plots/3INZP/src/Plots.jl:11
ERROR: Failed to precompile Plots [91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80] to /Users/owls/.julia/compiled/v1.3/Plots/ld3vC_39ter.ji.
Stacktrace:
 [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33
 [2] compilecache(::Base.PkgId, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1283
 [3] _require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:1024
 [4] require(::Base.PkgId) at ./loading.jl:922
 [5] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:917
```

Comment: There exist some reports issuing `Plots.jl` not working with version 1.3.0. I think installing 1.4.2 (stable version at that time) is the best option here. Otherwise you could check [Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/suddenly-cannot-use-plots-package/42385).